# How to determine a good cache time to live for live or semi-live data

Tags: caching

I write a lot of web-applications that poll data from a server. Often these are updated live, or at least semi-live, but generating the data often takes some time and should be cached to reduce server-strain. I do however have some trouble finding any good guides on how to best set an appropriate time to live, etc. Anyone have some good suggestions or rules of thumb?

Answer (score 1):

Use the longest duration you could afford your data to be stale as your TTL. If you can afford ten seconds, use a ten-second TTL. If you can afford one second, use a one-second TTL.

You can also look at the problem from the other side: have a single asynchronous server process continuously run the data generation query as often as possible and update the cache as fast as possible. This approach solves the cache stampede problem elegantly and you get an effective and optimum TTL of "how long does it take to generate the data?"